# Query is not work

Tags: java, mysql, sql, execution

```
select sum(value) as vv, officer 
from bulb 
where officer='" +jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0) + "'  && STR_TO_DATE(`startdate`,'%Y-%m-%d') 
BETWEEN '" + f2.getText() + "' AND '" + t2.getText() + "' 
group by carddtype
```

bulb = My Table Name
value,officer,startdate,carddtype = My columns
carddtype has duplicate data.

f2 and t2 are text fields variables.

**No error**. But no results. Without code below it works fine.

```
STR_TO_DATE(`startdate`,'%Y-%m-%d') 
BETWEEN '" + f2.getText() + "' AND '" + t2.getText() + "'
```

startdate

Comment: A couple of questions:
What is the significance of the second code section?
How is the text in f2 and t2 formatted?

Comment: `&&` looks suspicious.

Comment: It's also pretty poor practice to create a SQL string by concatenating raw SQL with user input.  At best you'll get sql errors everywhere, at worst you'll get someone injecting SQL maliciously.

Comment: to add to @MrTree comment please always use prepared statement. it will make the code easier to read on the long run

Comment: 2 upvotes for ***&&*** *?*

Comment: @MrTree Hellow sir.... I want to get some data for a date range. Therefore I used the second code. f2 and t2 formatted as yyyy-MM-dd .And also data has inserted to that format too..